# Yubico forward over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, gpg

I've been trying to forward my Yubico to perform sudo authentication without having to use the password

I've successfully performed SSH auth with Yubico no macOS 12 using `ssh -A user@server.com`

But after I login on the remote server I tried to check the card status but got the following output

```
user@server.com:~$ gpg --card-status
gpg: error getting version from 'scdaemon': Forbidden
gpg: selecting card failed: Forbidden
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Forbidden
```

The Yubico command also gives me the following error `Yubikey core error: no yubikey present`

So this is how I have my macOS set up the `gpg-agent.conf`

```
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /usr/local/MacGPG2/libexec/pinentry-mac.app/Contents/MacOS/pinentry-mac
default-cache-ttl 60
max-cache-ttl 120
# use-standard-socket
# extra-socket /Users/pedrocavaleiro/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

I got the local machine socket using the command `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-extra-socket` and on the remote machine using the command `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket`

I configured on the local machine `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host server.com
  HostName server.com
  ForwardAgent yes
  User user
  # RemoteForward /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/pedrocavaleiro/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
  RemoteForward /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/pedrocavaleiro/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
  RemoteForward /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh /Users/pedrocavaleiro/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

Also, on the remote machine I added the line `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes` to the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarted the `sshd` service

I've tried some other configurations from several tutorials on the internet even some provided by Yubico but without success.

I believe that after I get the Yubico being recognized on the remote machine I just need to follow these indications [Using Yubikey for sudo over SSH session](https://serverfault.com/questions/847783/using-yubikey-for-sudo-over-ssh-session) just adapting for Ubuntu

As of versions my local machine

```
macOS 12.4 (21F79)
ssh: OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.34
libgcrypt 1.8.9
```

For the remote machine

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-40-generic
ssh: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4
```

**UPDATE 1**
I updated the `gpg-agent.conf` by removing

```
use-standard-socket
extra-socket /Users/pedrocavaleiro/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

Also updated the `~/.ssh/config` and instead of using the `$.gpg-agent.extra` for the `RemoteForward` I used `$.gpg-agent` (visible in my original question)

These changes allowed me to successfully use the command `gpg --card-status` in the remote machine but a new issue presents itself

Trying `ssh-keygen -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so` outputs

```
C_GetSlotList failed: 48
cannot read public key from pkcs11
```

And `ykpamcfg -2 -v` still outputs `Yubikey core error: no yubikey present`

Answer (score 0):

You just can't share yubikey like that. You can share a smartcard via SSH by forwarding your GPG sockets, but dedicated yubikey tools relies on USB devices.